# Error while Aggregating data

Tags: r

I'm working on a bigdata dataframe.
 First column contains string values, and from the second column on it contains numerical datas.However in the second block described there are some NA that can't be eliminated deleting the whole row or column, because weill be even deleted important data
I want to create a new matrix that contains the same first column, but i want new numerical datas, calculated as the ratio between each row and a new row containing the sum of all the numerical values; this is what I did:

```
df1<- df[,-(1)]
tot<- colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)
ratio <- df1 / rep(tot, each = nrow(df1))
firstcol <- df[1]
data <- cbind(firstcol ,ratio)
```

After this, i wanted to aggregate all the values by the first column:

```
agg<- aggregate(. ~ firstColName, data, sum)
```

But doing this creates me an error:

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : no rows to   aggregate
```

I tried to make the same aggregation, excluding this part of the code:

```
ratio <- data / rep(tot, each = nrow(df1))
```

Having as result:

```
df1<- df[,-(1)]    
firstcol <- df[1]
data <- cbind(firstcol ,df1)
agg<- aggregate(. ~ firstColName, data, sum)
```

And in this case it worked perfectly, so I think that the reason is just the use of the ratio formula.
Should I use another way to make that operation?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, I created a new question.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi in the previous sample firstColName was VAL1, but in that case everything worked. Just using my real df which is a big data it does't work..i mean, the output before aggregation is correct, but aggregation gives me that mistake

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, i tried but it gives me the same error, the strange thing is that if I add a new row to `data` with the same structure of all the previous ones, it makes the aggregation, but the resulting dataframe contains only the new row

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, ok, thank you

Comment: Now the error is:  ` Error in model.frame.default(formula = cbind(colname,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'VAL1') `, there are some NA values shed in my file( from column 2 on), but i can't delete the entire row or column beacuse in following cells there are relevant data. I thought that NA linged on as NA without giving me those kind of problem. In few words due to the fact that there are NA is impossible to use  rep()?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, It worked. You're a genious and my hero...thank you so much

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, ahahah, i should tag you more often!!! (jokin' don't worry) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really difficult to guess what had happened, without actually watching you run your R code. Since you do not appear to show a good management of variable name, it is likely that you mask variable during your experiment.

We have wasted a great deal of time on guessing what happened. I suggest, we tried a **robust** code version. In the following, I provide you a function, taking your data frame as the only argument. **Variables inside the function won't conflict with those outside, even they have the same name**.

```
foo <- function (df) {
  error.default <- getOption("error")
  options(error = utils::recover)
  n <- nrow(df)
  value_df <- df[, -1]  ## data frame with values
  tot <- colSums(value_df, na.rm = TRUE)  ## column sums
  if (any(is.na(tot))) stop("NA detected in column sums! Exit!")
  ratio <- value_df / rep(tot, each = n)  ## rescaling
  string_df <- df[1]
  if (nrow(string_df) != nrow(ratio)) stop("dimension dismatch!!")
  cat("\n")
  data <- cbind(string_df ,ratio)
  cat("data summary:\n")
  cat(paste("number of rows: ", n, "\n",sep = ""))
  cat(paste("number of columns: ", ncol(data), "\n",sep = ""))
  ## NA summary: critical because aggregate will drop NA rows
  ## when all rows are dropped, aggregate complains "no row to aggregate"
  data <- na.omit(data)
  cat(paste("The number of non-NA rows passed to aggregate:", nrow(data))); cat("\n")
  cat("\n")
  if (nrow(data) == 0) stop("All rows are dropped! Exit!!")
  formula <- as.formula(paste(". ~", colnames(df)[1]))
  cat("the formula is: ")
  print(formula); cat("\n")
  agg <- aggregate(formula, data, FUN = sum)
  cat("aggregation success!!\n\n")
  options(error = error.default)
  return(agg)
  }

agg <- foo(df)
```

If there is any error pumping out, print the error message to me.

---

**Error detection**

Based on the report from the above function, when applied to your complete data, I am able to recover the scenario you are in, with the following simple examples.

Previously, the test data frame you gave is:

```
VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")
Num1 <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2) 
Num2 <- c(3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2,4, 4) 
Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 7) 
df <- data.frame(VAL1, Num1, Num2, Num3)
```

This will work correctly when you do aggregate. Now let's try something like this:

```
VAL1 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "BB", "DD", "AA", "DD")
Num1 <- c(NA, NA, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 2) 
Num2 <- c(3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2,4, 4) 
Num3 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA) 
df <- data.frame(VAL1, Num1, Num2, Num3)
```

Then, what will you get? Exactly what happened to your complete data set. Though each individual column does not have `NA` for all entries, they together flag all rows to have `NA`. **`Aggregate` will drop any rows containing at least one `NA`**. This is the default option for `aggregate`, see `?aggregate` for argument `na.action`.

---

**What can you do?**

Since you do not want to drop all `NA`, then you need to replace it with some sensible numeric values. It appears to me that setting all `NA` to 0 is reasonable in your problem. When you use `tot<- colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)`, this is equivalent to first setting all `NA` to 0, then applying the normal version `tot<- colSums(df1)`.

If you agree, we can do this:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 0   ## set all NA to 0

foo <- function (df) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  value_df <- df[, -1]  ## data frame with values
  tot <- colSums(value_df)  ## column sums
  ratio <- value_df / rep(tot, each = n)  ## rescaling
  string_df <- df[1]
  data <- cbind(string_df ,ratio)
  formula <- as.formula(paste(". ~", colnames(df)[1]))
  aggregate(formula, data, FUN = sum)
  }

agg <- foo(df)   ## use `NA` corrected df to aggregate
```

This should work.

Comment: I was wrong, it worked just because in row six you wrote:
 tot <- colSums(df1, na.rm = TRUE)  ## column sums,  using df1 it took the df sample I created before ( the one written in the other question) so he made the division. Changing df1 with value_df  gives me the same old error: `Error in foo(df) : 
  All rows are dropped! Exit!!`

Comment: is there a way with which I could group them by name and sum the numerical values?

Comment: I agree, due to the dimension of data is the most reasonable thing to do